# Mobile alerting app

Tags: mobile, alarm-clock

I am looking for solution where I can send message from command line (which I can program) to a mobile device and it will sound alarm like alarm clock - regardless of volume it will be loud and it will display whatever message. For both ios and android, but android is more needed :)

Comment: You could use a messenger app like Signal or Telegram and set the alarm sound as custom notification tone. As far as I know for both messenger there are command-line applications for sending messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is within the scope of [PagerDuty](https://www.pagerduty.com/) and its competitors (Victorops and Opsgenie).

Here is PagerDuty's documentation on how to configure the app to ignore do-not-disturb settings: https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/mobile-notification-settings